# Detox test requires bundle script address on development build of Expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, detox

I use the Detox library to test my React Native application.

My React Native application is based on Expo, and it is in development build instead of release because I still need to modify the source code, and modify and test it with Detox.

Following Detox's instructions, I run the following command to build the application to an apk file at the path "./android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk":

```
yarn detox build --configuration android.emu.debug
```

To run the test cases with Detox, I call the following command:

```
yarn detox test --configuration android.emu.debug
```

Detox initializes the application, but the test cases fail.

The reason is that when the application is built, it will be in development build. When Detox starts my application, my application will ask to enter the address of the React Native (expo) bundle script in order to load the components and perform the test. So I have to do this manually for each test case, which is not good.

Is there any way to solve this? Please guide me.